# Unable to send emails in laravel 5 app

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Hello I have a laravel 5 app which is working perfectly in local environment. But in production emails are not getting sent instead I get the exception below:

```
1/1 FatalErrorException in AstAnalyzer.php line 125:
    Cannot instantiate interface PhpParser\Parser

Path to file: /vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Analyzer/AstAnalyzer.php line 125
```

I don't get it because right now I am testing same function in local and is working. Every other path of the app is working except this one.

Below is the function:

```
public function update_password(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'new_password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            'new_password_confirmation' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = $this->user->get_user_by_id($id);
        $password = $request->get('new_password');
        $this->user->save_password($password, $id);

        // Send an email informing user that we have updated his password.
        Mail::queue('emails.password_update', ['user' => $user, 'password' => $password], function($message) use ($user){
            $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Account Password Updated');
        });
        $target_location = 'users/'. $id. '/profile';
        flash()->success('Password Updated Successfully');
        return redirect($target_location);
    }
```

Comment: It seems you have newer PHPParser version and outdated SuperClosure version. So `composer update` should be able to fix this issue

Comment: Thanks @RavishaHesh, let me fire the command and see

Comment: Hello @RavishaHesh, I have downloaded the lastest version of composer and ran `composer update` but still getting the error. What could be the problem. It is worth noting that other applications on the server are successfully sending emails and thesame application on local server is successfully sending email. What could be the problem? I have reuploaded all the  app files again but no change. Appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem. I ran a `composer update` which installed the lastest version of `nikic/php-parser` and equally the latest version `jeremeamia/superclosure`, but somehow, the `class Parser` which was formally use in nickic's package was now an Interface. `class Multiple` was now implementing the interface. So in `AstAnalyzer.php` in jeremeamia's package, that change was not made and instead `use PhpParser\Parser as CodeParser;` was used which is logical as an interface cannot be instantiated unless some binding is done. So as a quick fix, I used the previous version of nikic/php-parser.

Comment: Latest version of super-closure uses correct implementation(https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure/blob/master/src/Analyzer/AstAnalyzer.php#L136). That's why I asked you to do a composer update.

Comment: I did as you asked but issue continued.

Comment: Maybe laravel doesn't updates their composer.json inside vendor folder to get newer super-closure version.

Comment: Maybe it can be a caching related issue on my production server because locally the code works perfectly.

Comment: Out of curiousity I tried on another project on thesame server and every worked well

Comment: But with the project per this question, it only worked when I use the previous version of the php parser